# Removing directory of files slows down ENTIRE webserver

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx, ext4

I have a directory in `/var/www/media` with subdirectories containing a day's worth of many many images. Every night one of of these subdirectories is deleted using `rm -rf /var/www/media/1234`. Server is running Nginx/PHP on Ubuntu 12.04 with ext4 filesystem with journaling.

**Problem:** When doing the deletes, the entire web  server slows to a crawl. `iotop` shows 99% IO utilization by `jbd2/md3-8` and `md4_raid1`. I believe `jdb2` is working with ext4 journaling on the filesystem `/dev/md4` which hosts `/var/www/media` that we're deleting files off.

[image]
[image]

Its unacceptable to have the delete operations grind the server to a halt. What are my options here?

Do we have to set ext4 journaling to `data=writeback` to speed things up and avoid thrashing my server?

Comment: I've run into stuff like this before. What worked for me is batching the deletion into different subdirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the man page for `ionice`, which is intended for tuning this sort of thing.  It's fiddly though, as performance work always is.  The fact that pure disk I/O is killing your server says immediately that your service is disk-bound, and that's not a happy place to be (storage is a lot harder to scale than CPU!).  It may be that the best option is to add RAM to your boxes, but obviously we can't say without details.

Comment: I have under 50% RAM utilization on the server with 16GB total. I guess the IO bottleneck is at the harddisks.

Comment: Is something coming through and thrashing out all the disk cache by reading in the whole drive, maybe?  That would basically mean that your I/O caching isn't working, and that's something you need to fix.